# change context from qml

Tags: qml, pyside

I code some kind of installer with PySide and QML. By design, it must be multipage. And I want to divide slots to call from QML forms into different objects (in ideal, into modules, but as i understand, object with slots must inherit QObject, what modules can't do). So, when page is changed, 'controller' must be changed too, but, as I make it visible in QML with setContextProperty, I have a problem. Is there any way to call setContextProperty from QML? Or maybe some more correct way to do it exists? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need some 'mediator' object with functions defined as Q_INVOKABLE. So you set it visible to QML with setContextProperty and call from QML these functions as you need.